# Multipage form for silverpop

Tags: forms, shopify

I am currently doing some research on building a multipage form using silverpop but I couldn't find a relevant material online. Has anyone tried to do this? If so any pointers on how to implement it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I built a multi page webform outside of their UI in PHP and used their API to send in the values.

Do you have any experience with their API?

I guess you can also build one in their UI but use JQuery to hide and display sections of fields. I haven't tried out that method though.